# How to print out an XML String after it's become an object with PHP Simple XML

Tags: php, simplexml

This is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
$xml = '<root><item attr="1"><notes>item 1 notes</notes></item><item attr="2"><notes>item 2 notes</notes></item></root>';

$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string(xml);

//The XML Info will be modified and updated via loops and other stuff in here.

$updatedXml = $xmlObject converted back to string
```

To clarify, I'm converting an XML formatted string into a Simple XML object in PHP then in between i'm making alterations and updates to the XML object.

The thing I can't figure out is how to get it back into string format.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `asXML` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php